# matplotlab: plt.figure() creates empty figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, arima

I am playing with the example at

https://github.com/seanabu/seanabu.github.io/blob/master/Seasonal_ARIMA_model_Portland_transit.ipynb

However, on my own Jupyter Notebook, the following piece of code creates an empty figure. Any idea? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two figures. Simply remove the first creation of the empty figure fig = plt.figure().

Here is a minimal example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import statsmodels.api as sm  
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

dat = sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas().data.dropna()
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(dat.co2, freq=12)  
fig = decomposition.plot()   
fig .set_size_inches(15, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `plt.show()` at the end.